Natural Equation Of Cycloid
Consider one arch of the cycloid
$$\vec{r}(\theta)=(\theta-\sin(\theta))\hat{i}+(1-\cos(\theta))\hat{j}\;\;\;\;\;0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$$
I am supposed to show that the arclength s and the radius of curvature $\rho$ are related by the equation $s^2+\rho^2=16$. First I calculated the arclength which I calculated as
$$s=\int_0^\theta\sqrt{2-2\cos(\theta')}\;d\theta'=\int_0^\theta4\sin\left(\frac{\theta'}{2}\right)\;d\theta'$$
When I take evaluate this definite integral I get $4-4\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$ but if I just take the antiderivative I get $-4\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+c$. I go onto to calculate the curvature $\kappa$ and then take its reciprocal to get the radius of curvature which I got as
$$\rho=4\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
At first I used the arclength I calculated using the definite integral and I got
$$s^2+\rho^2=32-32\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
But when I use the antiderivative instead of the definite integral with $c=0$, I get the correct answer
$$s^2+\rho^2=16$$
Am I supposed to use the antiderivative or the definite integral for arclength? I am pretty sure arclength is defined with a definite integral that has a variable bound when I used that I got the wrong answer.
